# iOS Submit Forms in Javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

Yes you read that right. I feel a little silly asking this but haven't been able to come up with a definitive answer, just vague hypotheses.

I've got embedded web forms in my app that are loaded by a UIWebView and once filled out, need to be submitted.

Now, I know that it is possible to pass this data to the objective-c code through window.location, then send it off in a POST url request from there. However, I want to know if it is possible to skip this step and send it straight to the form on my server from the html/javascript in my embedded web forms.

I.e. can I just make the form point straight to my server from the javascript inside the embedded form, and skip the iOS altogether?

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand your question - if you load the webpage in a UIWebView and the user interacts with a form on the page then when they are done it'll behave just as if the page was loaded in Safari. This is the norm, passing the data to objective-C is the un-norm. So not sure what you are asking as what you have described as apparently wanting to happen is the usual situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, skip the iOS altogether. Why wouldn't you?

> can I just ... skip the iOS altogether?

You are basically just using the UIWebView as a shell to run your web app in. A lot of app do this so they can have a web app in the app store. There is no need to do any code like that in Objective-C.

Comment: Did you have any other questions about this? I don't anticipate a lot of response here, since skipping the iOS is clearly the way to go. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I apparently just had a brainfart on this one. My old model was using tricks to pass data to objective-c, so I had noticed that it is still calling the delegate method and I wasn't sure if it was blocking it. I guess that was the gist of my question - whether or not obj-c would block the web-view from doing certain things, but the answer is emphatically no. Thanks for the response.